# Simple jQuery progress bar percentage

Tags: php, jquery, progress-bar

I have been trying to find a simple tutorial that shows the basics of how to add a progress percentage to my file upload, I have already built my file upload part so I don't want a plugin that comes with both, I want to be able to code the progress bar myself, but I need some help on how to do this. I want to learn how it works, I don't just want some plugin that does it all for me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

I'm just interested in how to get the percentage of the file upload, not really on the progress bar itself. I want to be able to have an accurate percentage.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Look here:

http://jquery.malsup.com/form/progress.html

Try this:-

**this is my html code**

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<title>File Upload Progress Demo #1</title>
<style>
body { padding: 30px }
form { display: block; margin: 20px auto; background: #eee; border-radius: 10px; padding: 15px }

.progress { position:relative; width:400px; border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 1px; border-radius: 3px; }
.bar { background-color: #B4F5B4; width:0%; height:20px; border-radius: 3px; }
.percent { position:absolute; display:inline-block; top:3px; left:48%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>File Upload Progress Demo #1</h1>
    <code>&lt;input type="file" name="myfile"></code>
        <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="uploadedfile"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload File to Server">
    </form>

    <div class="progress">
        <div class="bar"></div >
        <div class="percent">0%</div >
    </div>

    <div id="status"></div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script>
(function() {

var bar = $('.bar');
var percent = $('.percent');
var status = $('#status');

$('form').ajaxForm({
    beforeSend: function() {
        status.empty();
        var percentVal = '0%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
        var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    complete: function(xhr) {
     bar.width("100%");
    percent.html("100%");
        status.html(xhr.responseText);
    }
}); 

})();       
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**my php code**

```
<?php
$target_path = "uploads/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
```

Comment: This is my tested code. File upload with percentage progress bar. try it.

Comment: SAVIOR. This answer saved me after 3 days of continuous struggle. Thanks a lot bhaijaan Abid.

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev, the whole point of posting code as well as the link, is if the link becomes unavailable (temporarily or permanently) the code is still available on this site for people to look at and use. Do not just post links as answers, always provide the code.

Comment: @PaparazzoKid, I agree  on what you've said and back then, I don't remember now, what I exactly meant but it wasn't about proposing the idea of posting codes as external link. There was some unnecessary examples of how to include jQuery, I think..