# How to get the current % of uploaded file

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload

```
progress: function (e, data) {

    //$('#file_upload_progress').val(data.progressInterval);
    $('#file_upload_progress2').css('width', data.progressInterval + '%');
    console.log(data.progressInterval);
    /*
        for(a in data) {
            alert(a);           
        }
    */
}
```

I am using the Jquery file uploader, when i use the `data.progressInterval` i get 100%, is this the right way to get %?

Comment: I don't know about jQuerry, but normally, you need to catch `HTTPRequest.upload.onprogress` then you get the percentage as `event.loaded * 100 / event.total;` in the callback.

Comment: Did you check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131999/simple-jquery-progress-bar-percentage

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
progress: function (e, data) {
    $('#file_upload_progress2').css('width', parseInt(t.loaded/t.total*100,10) + '%')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The XMLHttpRequest Level 2 has these feature.see [Monitoring data transfers with progress events](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/xhr2/)