# Redirect to another page after form submit using jquery progress bar

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I have a form that sends text and images to a php file that saves it to a database and then it redirects to either a success page or a fail to post page.
I followed the solution [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131999/simple-jquery-progress-bar-percentage) but i don't want it to show me a success/failed message. I want it to redirect me to the pages defined on the php file.
Here is a short example of the form

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="uploadedfile"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File to Server">
</form>

<div class="progress">
    <div class="bar"></div >
    <div class="percent">0%</div >
</div>

<div id="status"></div>
```

This is the script

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js
</script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script>
    (function() {

    var bar = $('.bar');
    var percent = $('.percent');
    var status = $('#status');

    $('form').ajaxForm({
         beforeSend: function() {
           status.empty();
           var percentVal = '0%';
           bar.width(percentVal)
           percent.html(percentVal);
         },
         uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
           var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
           bar.width(percentVal)
           percent.html(percentVal);
         },
         complete: function(xhr) {
           bar.width("100%");
           percent.html("100%");
           status.html(xhr.responseText);
         }
    }); 

    })();       
 </script>
```

And insert.php is something like this

```
<?php
$target_path = "uploads/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    header("Location: post_success.php");
} else{
    header("Location: post_fail.php");
}
?>
```

But instead of following the "header(location....)" it shows the contents of that page below the form instead of redirecting. I'm not familiar with javascript or jquery and can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use javascript to do the redirect. So will send back the appropriate url instead from server

PHP

```
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "post_success.php";
} else{
     echo "post_fail.php";
}
```

JS

```
complete: function(xhr) {
    bar.width("100%");
    percent.html("100%");
    window.location = xhr.responseText;//redirect to url returned from server
}
```

Comment: Now it gets stuck on insert.php echoing post_success.php as a string.

Comment: what do you mean `stuck`? I just noticed I left in `Location:` by mistake on the fail url and fixed it

Comment: Never mind, it's working now. Your solution wasn't working until i noticed i had added the jquery.js file twice. 
"window.location = xhr.responseText;" was the solution